# Margin between 2 elements, one of which has "position: fixed;"

Tags: css, css-position, margin

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8Lvypo05/) to better understand my problem.
When either one of the 2 lists separated by the yellow divider becomes long the vertical scroll bar of the browser appears, which is fine. However, when you scroll down to the **very** bottom the text ***Example_2.1*** will not be seen, because it's hidden by the **ATTENTION!** box, which has a **position: fixed;** value.

```css
.divider {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fec303;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.meanings_and_examples {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

ol.circle {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  line-height: 1.6;
}

ol.circle>li {
  counter-increment: item;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  margin-left: 2.5em;
}

ol.circle>li::before {
  margin-right: 1em;
  margin-left: -2.7em;
  content: counter(item);
  background: #1f2c60;
  border-radius: 100%;
  color: white;
  width: 1.7em;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 2.5em;
}

.meaning {
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  width: auto;
  text-align: left;
  color: #1f2c60;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  font-size: 3vw;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.example {
  width: auto;
  text-align: left;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.example_translated {
  width: auto;
  text-align: left;
  color: #5d78e5;
}

.comment_box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: left;
  background: #fff8e5;
}

.comment_title {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(231, 237, 22, 0.58);
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0.5em #f92504, 0 0 0.5em #f92504, 0 0 0.5em #f92504;
  font-size: 3vw;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.comment_text {
  width: auto;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  color: #1f2c60;
  margin: 15px 10px 20px;
  text-shadow: none;
  font-size: 2vw;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<div class="meaning">
  <ol class="circle">
    <li>Text_1</li>
    <div class="example">
      <ul>
        <li>Example_1.1</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <li>Text_2</li>
    <div class="example">
      <ul>
        <li>Example_2.1</li>
        <li>Example_2.2</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </ol>
</div>

<div class="divider"></div>

<div class="meaning">
  <ol class="circle">
    <li>Text_1</li>
    <div class="example">
      <ul>
        <li>Example_1.1</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <li>Text_2</li>
    <div class="example">
      <ul>
        <li>Example_2.1</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </ol>
</div>

<div class="comment_box">
  <div class="comment_title">ATTENTION!
  </div>
  <div class="comment_text">Comment: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor...
  </div>
</div>
```

How do i set a margin *above* the **ATTENTION!** box so that the last line of the list is always seen?
It's essential that parameters of the *list itself* (like intervals between lines or paragraphs) stay **the same** as they are now.

Thank you!

Comment: Since the `comment-box` is set to fixed, you can't set the margin on the comment box. You will need to set padding or margin on the last div. You can't do this with CSS alone, because it can't calculate the height of the `.comment-box`. You can either set a fixed padding/margin on the last `meaning` div, or you can use JS to calculate the height of the `.comment-box` and apply that value as padding/margin on the `meaning` div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the way you can do it with JS. What this does is gets the height of the `comment-box` and then sets the margin on the last `meaning` div.

```js
// Need to set an id on the comment-box. Now we select it.
let comment_box = document.getElementById('comment-box');
// Get the comment_box calculated height
let comment_box_height = comment_box.clientHeight;
// Gather all of the .meaning divs.
let meaning_array = document.querySelectorAll('.meaning');
// get the last meaning div from the node list.
let last = [].slice.call(meaning_array).pop();
// set the margin on the last meaning div.
last.style.marginBottom = comment_box_height + 'px';
```

```css
.divider {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fec303;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.meanings_and_examples {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

ol.circle {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  line-height: 1.6;
}

ol.circle>li {
  counter-increment: item;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  margin-left: 2.5em;
}

ol.circle>li::before {
  margin-right: 1em;
  margin-left: -2.7em;
  content: counter(item);
  background: #1f2c60;
  border-radius: 100%;
  color: white;
  width: 1.7em;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 2.5em;
}

.meaning {
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  width: auto;
  text-align: left;
  color: #1f2c60;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  font-size: 3vw;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.example {
  width: auto;
  text-align: left;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.example_translated {
  width: auto;
  text-align: left;
  color: #5d78e5;
}

.comment_box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: left;
  background: #fff8e5;
}

.comment_title {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(231, 237, 22, 0.58);
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0.5em #f92504, 0 0 0.5em #f92504, 0 0 0.5em #f92504;
  font-size: 3vw;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.comment_text {
  width: auto;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  color: #1f2c60;
  margin: 15px 10px 20px;
  text-shadow: none;
  font-size: 2vw;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<div class="meaning">
  <ol class="circle">
    <li>Text_1</li>
    <div class="example">
      <ul>
        <li>Example_1.1</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <li>Text_2</li>
    <div class="example">
      <ul>
        <li>Example_2.1</li>
        <li>Example_2.2</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </ol>
</div>

<div class="divider"></div>

<div class="meaning">
  <ol class="circle">
    <li>Text_1</li>
    <div class="example">
      <ul>
        <li>Example_1.1</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <li>Text_2</li>
    <div class="example">
      <ul>
        <li>Example_2.1</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </ol>
</div>

<div class="comment_box" id="comment-box">
  <div class="comment_title">ATTENTION!
  </div>
  <div class="comment_text">Comment: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor...
  </div>
</div>
```

The other way, as suggested is just set a static margin to the last `meaning` div. To do that, you'll have to wrap them in a container so you can use the pseudo `:last-child` selector e.g.:

```
.meaning:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 120px /* or whatever height you decide */
}
```

Comment: Your CSS solution is fantastic in its simplicity, thank you!

Comment: @HexenSage you should mark an answer as accepted so future visitors know what helped you solve the issue.

Comment: Oh, sure! I'm new at Stackoverflow - how can i mark an accepted answer please? Can't find a button/link which supposes this action... :-(

Comment: I think there is a grey checkbox next to the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your HTML code in a div and give it a margin-bottom like below:

```css
.divider {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fec303;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.meanings_and_examples {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

ol.circle {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  line-height: 1.6;
}

ol.circle > li {
  counter-increment: item;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  margin-left: 2.5em;
 }

ol.circle > li::before {
  margin-right: 1em;
  margin-left: -2.7em;
  content: counter(item);
  background: #1f2c60;
  border-radius: 100%;
  color: white;
  width: 1.7em;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
 }

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 2.5em;
}

.meaning {
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  width: auto;
  text-align: left;
  color: #1f2c60;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  font-size: 3vw;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.example {
  width: auto;
  text-align: left;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.example_translated {
  width: auto;
  text-align: left;
  color: #5d78e5;
}

.comment_box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: left;
  background: #fff8e5;
}

.comment_title {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(231, 237, 22, 0.58);
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0.5em #f92504, 0 0 0.5em #f92504, 0 0 0.5em #f92504;
  font-size: 3vw;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.comment_text {
  width: auto;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  color: #1f2c60;
  margin: 15px 10px 20px;
  text-shadow: none;
  font-size: 2vw;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<div  style="margin-bottom:100px">
<div class="meaning" >
<ol class="circle">
  <li>Text_1</li>
<div class="example">
   <ul>
      <li>Example_1.1</li>     
   </ul>
</div>
  <li>Text_2</li>
<div class="example">
   <ul>
      <li>Example_2.1</li>     
      <li>Example_2.2</li>     
   </ul>
</div>
</ol>
</div>

<div class="divider"></div>

<div class="meaning">
<ol class="circle">
  <li>Text_1</li>
<div class="example">
   <ul>
      <li>Example_1.1</li>     
   </ul>
</div>
  <li>Text_2</li>
<div class="example">
   <ul>
      <li>Example_2.1</li>     
   </ul>
</div>
</ol>
</div>
</div>
<div class="comment_box">
<div class="comment_title">ATTENTION!
</div>
<div class="comment_text">Comment: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor...
</div>
</div>
```